# alignment of a div

Tags: html

What is the default behaviour of a `div`?

I noticed that even if a put a width for a div let's say 100px,
if i put a 2nd div with the same width will put it on the second line.so by default doesn't matter the width. it puts it on different lines?
in this case i understand the need of float.
I thought that any element i put in a html page,they will be side by side unless i add a break element or paragraph or something with that role.
Or maybe i do not use it correctly the `div` for this kind of alignment,but i really want to 
clarify this for good.

Answer (score 1):

A div element is, by default, [`display: block`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#display-prop).

> This value causes an element to generate a block box.

The [rendering of them is described here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-boxes)

> Block-level elements are those elements of the source document that are formatted visually as blocks (e.g., paragraphs). The following values of the 'display' property make an element block-level: 'block', 'list-item', and 'table'.
>
> Block-level boxes are boxes that participate in a block formatting context.

and [then here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting)

> In a block formatting context, boxes are laid out one after the other, vertically, beginning at the top of a containing block.

To stop this kind of rendering, you can use `float` to cause block level elements to bubble up beside each other. You can also modify the display property of the div.

Answer (score 1):

Divs are *block-level* elements which mean they stack...like blocks. Although it sounds reasonable that since the width would allow them to fit side-by-side without a float, this is not how they are designed to behave.

If an element is an *inline* element as opposed to a *block*, its behavior is to fit side-by-side. You can force this behavior on a div if you would like by tying the two ideas together. You can do something like:

```
<div style="display:inline-block"></div>
```

This will allow the div to maintain its other block properties but allow it to fit inline as text and images would and, if this the your desired goal, avoid the use of *float*.

Answer (score 0):

The DIV by default takes 100% of the screen, even if you set it width the space on the right cannot be occupied by anything.

Try this:

The way to have two div on the same line would be to make them float:

```
<div style = 'float:left;width:500px;background-color:red;color:white;'>Hey</div>

<div style = 'float:left;width:100px;'> There</div>
```